# Is one of the hyperplane partitions of a irreducible root system always generate the whole Weyl group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

Let $\Delta$ be a irreducible root system and $\Delta^+$ be its positive roots.

We say a subset $\Delta^{\prime}\subset \Delta^+$ can generate the Weyl group if reflections of roots in $\Delta^{\prime}$ generate the whole Weyl group.

If we simply consider a partition of $\Delta^+$ into disjoint union
$$
\Delta^+=\Delta^+_1\amalg \Delta^+_2,
$$
then it is quite possible that  neither $\Delta^+_1$ nor $\Delta^+_2$ can generate the Weyl group. For example take $\Delta=B_2$ and $\Delta^+_1=$ the two long positive roots and $\Delta^+_2=$ the two short positive roots. For example $\Delta^+$ itself or the set $\Sigma$ of simple roots generates the Weyl group.

> > My question is: if we consider a partition of $\Delta^+$ by a hyperplane which does not contain any root. Then it is true that either $\Delta^+_1$ or $\Delta^+_2$ can generate the  Weyl group by root reflections in the above sense?

Comment: I feel like there should be a way to reduce this to considering $2$-dimensional subspaces...

Comment: I have the impression this is trivially true. Changing the hyperplane corresponds to a different choice of positive roots. So, your example already covers this.

Comment: @user66288 This is not trivially true. Actually let $\Phi^+$ and $\Psi^+$ be too positive root systems. My question is equivalent to the question whether one of $\Phi^+\cap \Psi^+$ and $\Phi^+\cap \Psi^-$ generates the whole Weyl group.

Comment: You are right. I got it wrong.